# why does forex platforms provide high leverage but shares and others dont

Tags: leverage

I have been looking at a few forex platform and they provide high leverage with overnigh fees close to LIBOR. The same is not true for shares on stocks and they provide 5x leverage with higher interest rates. Why is this?

Comment: I would be cautious with these ultra high leverage FX platforms, very cautious. Most customers lose money.

Comment: If they are regulated by FCA , do you think it is okay to use them?